# ActivityNotFoundException only on some devices for the same apk

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm receiving ActivityNotFoundException crash reports on certain devices for an activity within my app. The crash message is: `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{*}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {*}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

I've confirmed that the activity is properly declared in the manifest and works without issue on other devices. How is it possible to encounter this error only on certain devices?"

Comment: start the activity within try/block and share logcat here

Comment: simple will declare your class name in manifest

Comment: @Elango It is not possible, since the crash is not happening on test devices.

Comment: @sureshmadaparthi I've mentioned in the question that I've declared it in the manifest!

Comment: then check with other devices , without proper code / logcat how can we solve  the issue? check android device verions

Comment: @Elango I know that it's difficult to solve without logcat, but I myself do not have access to logcat. This is happening on some of user devices, and I was asking this question in hope of finding someone who has faced the same problem before.